# NSPredicate Inside a SUBQUERY

Tags: swift, core-data, nspredicate, nsexpression

I'm trying to write a SUBQUERY for an NSPredicate. My problem is I don't have the query on hand for the predicate portion of the SUBQUERY. Is there a way to nest an NSPredicate inside the SUBQUERY?

For example this is what I have tried:

```
let ordersPredicate = NSPredicate()//some predicate passed in
//how do I use the ordersPredicate inside the subquery??
let subQueryPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "SUBQUERY(orders, $x,'%@').@count > 0", ordersPredicate.predicateFormat)
```

Update: I had to do a dirty workaround for now by executing the first predicate and doing an ANY IN query. Its lame :( because I'm executing the ordersPredicate elsewhere as well later in the pipeline..

```
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest()//blah
fetchRequest.predicate = orderPredicate
let orders = //execute fetch
let subQueryPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "SUBQUERY(orders, $x, ANY $x in %@).@count > 0", orders)
```

Comment: could you post your Order class/definition and explain what you want to achieve?

Comment: In the workaround you don't need a subquery, `ANY orders in %@` will do. Why do you set `returnObjectsAsFaults` to false?

Comment: If you want to use a predicate in a subquery, the predicate should be something like `$x.orderNumber = 10`, with`$x`. It is possible to convert the predicate but might be easier to redesign the pipeline.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.
@vikingosegundo I'm trying to Query a Branch Entity which has a toMany relationships to orders. Basically I want to query for any branches inside a predicate for Orders.

Comment: @Willeke I copied that code, but in context it doesn't make sense to set returnObjectsAsFalse. I'm looking into redesigning some things thanks for the suggestions

Comment: @Willeke, you say it's possible to convert the predicate to be like $x.whatever, how can I do this?

Comment: You have to build a copy of the predicate. Replace keypath expressions by an function expression with a variable expression, selector `valueForKeyPath:` and the keypath.

Comment: @NathanHart Do you need to use a second fetch request?  Could you just use the inverse relationship on the Order entity to achieve the same result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to some pointers from @Willeke I was able to come up with a solution.

```
public extension NSPredicate{
    public func stringForSubQuery(prefix:String) -> String{
        var predicateString = ""
        if let predicate = self as? NSCompoundPredicate{
            for (index, subPredicate) in predicate.subpredicates.enumerate(){

                if let subPredicate = subPredicate as? NSComparisonPredicate{
                    predicateString = "\(predicateString) \(prefix)\(subPredicate.predicateFormat)"
                }
                else if let subPredicate = subPredicate as? NSCompoundPredicate{
                    predicateString = "\(predicateString) (\(subPredicate.stringForSubQuery(prefix)))"
                }
                //if its not the last predicate then append the operator string
                if index < predicate.subpredicates.count - 1 {
                    predicateString = "\(predicateString) \(getPredicateOperatorString(predicate.compoundPredicateType))"
                }
            }
        }
        return predicateString
    }
    private func getPredicateOperatorString(predicateType: NSCompoundPredicateType) -> String{
        switch(predicateType){
        case .NotPredicateType: return "!"
        case .AndPredicateType: return "&&"
        case .OrPredicateType: return "||"
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the usage

```
let ordersPredicate = NSPredicate()//some predicate passed in
let ordersPredicateFormat = orderPredicate.stringForSubQuery("$x.")
let subQueryPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "SUBQUERY(orders, $x, \(ordersPredicateFormat)).@count > 0")
```

Answer (score 4):

For anyone coming across this in the future, you don't need to build the predicate string yourself, just use `predicateFormat` directly in your subquery string. It is already properly escaped, so use string interpolation.

```swift
let ordersPredicate = NSPredicate()
// Add it to the query with string interpolation
let subQueryPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "SUBQUERY(orders, $x, \(ordersPredicate.predicateFormat)).@count > 0")
```

If you try to pass it as an argument, it will try to escape the string again, which will probably not work.

```swift
// Don't do this!
let subQueryPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "SUBQUERY(orders, $x, %@).@count > 0", ordersPredicate.predicateFormat)
```